# How do I create cluster singleton using FSharp API?

Tags: f#, akka.net

I'm not sure how do i spawn a cluster singleton using FSharp API. Should i use [spwane] or [spawnOpt] ? and how one does that ?

Comment: Have you checked those 2 links ? 
http://getakka.net/docs/clustering/cluster-singleton
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239608/how-to-create-an-actor-in-a-clustered-configuration-in-f

Comment: I did, it is just doesn't make sense to me when it comes to fsharp. like how do i supply props class to it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create cluster singleton using standard Akka.FSharp API. *Reason behind that is that Akka.FSharp API already hit v1.0 before the shape of the cluster singleton API was even known.*

You can however use [Akkling.Cluster.Sharding](https://github.com/Horusiath/Akkling/wiki) library (Akkling is an alternative F# API for Akka.NET) and establish cluster singleton by using [spawnSingleton](https://github.com/Horusiath/Akkling/blob/fa6474689475af0c327dfbfda1c2b1dbfcc54f40/src/Akkling.Cluster.Sharding/ClusterSingleton.fs#L24) function.